# USB Interaction between device and host (Endpoint - Buffer - HostController)

Tags: usb, buffer, interrupt, endpoint

What I know:

- USB Device (Mouse) has an Interrupt IN Endpoint where outgoing data to host ist stored.
- Host polls this Interrupt IN Endpoint and writes the data to a buffer.

Where can I find this buffer? I tried very hard to find it in the Technical Manual of my motherboard (USB...Controller ... Buffer) but I could not find this register.

So is the HostController using its own buffer for storing the Endpoint IN data from the device or is the Host Conroller Mapping it to other registers?

And if there is an action, (eg mouse movement or click), does the USB Host Controller cause an interrupt? 
Where can I find this stored/buffered data?

I am working with ubuntu and by looking into `/proc/interrupts` I can find the `EHCI_HCD:USB2` Controller with IRQ Number of connected USB Device (mouse) ...

Maybe anyone can help me with understanding this usb Enpoint => HostController => Interrupt --- Mechanism.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Where can I find this buffer? I tried very hard to find it in the Technical Manual of my motherboard (USB...Controller ... Buffer) but I could not find this register.

> This buffer comes from HID class driver in the form of URB. So its a software buffer.

So is the HostController using its own buffer for storing the Endpoint IN data from the device or is the Host Conroller Mapping it to other registers?

> As I said earlier, there is no register in the host controller to store the data. Host controller uses the software buffer passed by the HCD.

And if there is an action, (eg mouse movement or click), does the USB Host Controller cause an interrupt? Where can I find this stored/buffered data?

> No. There will not be any interrupt. You will be polling the Interrupt endpoint to get the status. Interrupts are used by the host controller to notify the completion of a transfer which is Interrupt IN transfer in your case.

To make it clear, please see the below diagram of the Transfer Descriptor. The host controller uses the "Buffer pointer" to store or retrieve data in case of IN and OUT transaction respectively. To know more about Transfer Descriptor please read EHCI specification.

[image]

Comment: Dear @Shaibal. Thank you for your answer. So Host controller causes an interrupt when URB is completed? Registered to the generic Interrupt Controller? For informing the core? What is the source of the pic "buffer pointer" ... i could not find an transfer descriptor described in the USB Specs.You have a source for this? Best regards

Comment: Yes host controller causes interrupt for three situations - transfer complete, port change events, Host internal errors. The interrupt will be registered to Generic Interrupt controller. Please see the "ehci specification" document from intel. Chapter 3 section 5 for the data structure diagram and details about the buffers. :)